# SMS Sender is not displayed correctly via OVH SMS Service with Sending Jobs API

Tags: symfony, sms, ovh

I successfully sent an SMS using the **OVH SMS service** through the **Sending Jobs** API (***POST API: /sms/{serviceName}/jobs***).

However, upon receiving the message, I noticed that the specified sender information was not taken into consideration. Instead of seeing the sender name "***SOCIETY***" the recipient only sees a numeric sender ID in the "from" section of the SMS.

Below is the code snippet I used for sending the SMS:

```
$smsServices = $ovh->get('/sms/');

$message = [
    "charset" => "UTF-8",
    "class" => "phoneDisplay",
    "coding" => "7bit",
    "message" => sprintf('SOCIETY - Code de vérification: %s', $code),
    "noStopClause" => false,
    "sender" => "SOCIETY",
    "priority" => "high",
    "receivers" => [$this->formatPhoneNumber($phoneNumber)],
    "senderForResponse" => true
];

$ovh->post('/sms/' . $smsServices[0] . '/jobs', $message);
```

I have verified that the payload includes the "***sender***" option with the desired sender name. However, it seems that the sender name is not being properly displayed to the recipients, and instead, only the numeric sender ID is shown.

I would appreciate any assistance or insights on how to resolve this issue and ensure that the sender name "***SOCIETY***" is correctly displayed when sending SMS messages via the OVH SMS service.

Thanks.